# single container page referring to multiple urls

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, url-routing, servlet-filters, opencms

In opencms i want to access single container page with multiple urls

for Ex: consider a **xyz** container page
        i want access the container page with multiple urls reffered as below

```
    1>localhost:8080/xyz/abc

    2>localhost:8080/xyz/abc?id=xxxabc.
```

Suggest me how to achieve this.
i am trying to achieve this using http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

suggest me other options also

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does the second url show if not the container page? If the first url shows it fine, I don't see why appending any url parameter should not work or why you would need to use a urlrewrite.

Comment: both urls will show same container page, in this aspect resource i.e. container page is present at path localhost:8080/xyz. But urls will be as shown above. i need  to call  resource internally with out changing url in browser how can i achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I am using `http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/` filter for removing opencms/opencms in url.

Regular expressions can be used for assigning multiple urls to single container page. Tuckey filter provides urlrewrite.xml, specify the rule tag here

```
<rule>
        <from>/products/([0-9]+)</from>
        <to>/products/index.jsp?product_id=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned tuckey urlrewrite should be fine; you would need to configure it as a FORWARD.

If you want to do it within your OpenCms JSP template directly, you can do a forward directly in JSP like this:

```
<% if(request.getParameter("id")==null) request.getRequestDispatcher("/xyz/abc?id=xxxabc").forward(request, response);%>
```

But such code in JSP is usually not best-practice. Using tuckey urlrewrite is probably a cleaner approach.

Comment: here my url in browser will be like localhost:8080/xyz/abc, but resource is at localhost:8080/xyz so there is the problem. we can't use forward in the jsp

Comment: I don't see why you cannot use a forward there? Does localhost:8080/xyz/abc not get served through a jsp template? Is it a Java-coded servlet? What kind of resource is it?

Comment: Resource is opencms container page, this is present at localhost:8080/xyz.

Comment: In that case, you can create a new jsp file within OpenCms at localhost:8080/xyz/abc and put above forwarding into that jsp file, pointing to localhost:8080/xyz. (Note that the urls you mention here differ from your original post; in the original post, you have just the ?id-parameter as a difference, while here you have /xyz/abc which should lead to /xyz.). That case is actually simpler. I don't see why you couldn't simply create a new resource at /xyz/abc with a forward in it.